# Using RVM Gemsets & Bundler & RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler, gemset

I use RVM to manage Ruby versions.
In my project I use Bundler to manage gems for the project.

RVM also have gemsets.
Gem in gemset don't have a connection with Bundler's gem. ***← Is this correct?***
I came to this conclusion because gem files stored in different locations:
RVM gemset: `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myApp`
Bundler: `[my_app_dir]/vendor/bundle/gems`
So app uses Bundler gems, not RVM gemset gems.

But when I add gem to my Gemfile, RubyMine IDE shows me warning, that this gem is not in RVM gemset. So I add this gem to RVM gemset also (just to get rid of this warning).

So the questions are:

1. Is there any good reason to add gems in both places (RVM Gemset and Gemfile)?
2. If no, then why RubyMine warning me about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Is there any good reason to add gems in both places (RVM Gemset and Gemfile)?

The gemset is incidental, the Gemfile is absolutely the place to declare your dependencies. Where you store those gems is up to you.

It sounds like Bundler is configured to store them in a project-local path, but you're expecting them to be in a gemset. Bundler got that configuration by running `bundle install --path vendor/bundle/gems` at some point. It stores that configuration in its project configuration file at `project_dir/.bundle/config`:

```
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle/gems
```

I'm unfamiliar with Rubymine, but if you run the Rails server using Bundler (i.e. `bundle exec rails server`) you can ignore that warning. Bundler will correctly load the gems listed in the Gemfile.

If you want to use a gemset *instead* of the Bundler cache, you can just remove that line from the Bundler configuration file and reinstall your gems with `bundle install`.

> 1. If no, then why RubyMine warning me about this?

My guess is that Rubymine is not reading the Bundler project configuration (in `project_path/.bundle/config`) and does not understand where the gems are installed.

Comment: Removed `BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle/gems`. Now gems installed in the correct dir. Thanks!

Comment: Do we need both gemsets as well as bundler to manage the gems?

Comment: @AnkitDhingra No, gemsets are not required to manage gems. Bundler will load the correct dependencies for you as long as you use `bundle exec` before any command.

Answer (score 2):

You (or if you are working in a team, somebody of your team) has once done a `bundle install` and specified a installation-folder. In your case `vendor/bundle/gems`. Bundle remembers this setting and all next invocations of the bundle command will use the same path.

There is a good reason to do it that way: your application-folder will contain all requirements and will be easier to redistribute (for instance).

Now if you want that bundle installs your gems in the normal locations, you can do the following:

- run `bundle install --system` which will use the default location
- alternatively: bundle stores it settings in a config file, I think `.bundle/config` and you can
  check that one as well. Normally it is not needed, since `bundle install --system` will set that 
  correctly again.
- then you can safely remove the `vendor/bundle/gems` folder

Comment: `bundle install --system` still installs it in `vendor/bundle/gems`, but removing `BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle/gems` from `.bundle/config` helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, something's wrong, you shouldn't have anything under vendor/bundle, it should all be under ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myApp and perhaps ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global assuming your .rvmrc (or.ruby-version) is setup correctly.

What does "gem env" look like? Also "bundle env"?

Comment: [gem_env](http://alex-fedoseev-files.s3.amazonaws.com/gem_env.txt)  &  
[bundle_env](http://alex-fedoseev-files.s3.amazonaws.com/bundle_env.txt)

Comment: Ok, that's odd, Bundler shows the correct gempath (/Users/Alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@myBlog:/Users/Alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global). By any chance did you run bundle before setting-up rvm? Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: Also, what does RubyMine show as the gem env (Tools -> Show gem environment)?

Comment: Maybe. I don't remember, it's my first app)

Answer (score 1):

So this just took me 3 days, since nothing else I was finding here was helping. I also run multiple projects through RubyMine at the same time (and different versions) so setting my GEM_PATH and launching from command-line doesn't work for me. I use IntelliJ with RM plugin, this *should* work on RM standalone.

Bundler seems to install custom gems, or gems from custom repos, in a different directory than gems from rubygems, or github.

> /Users/YOURUSER/.rvm/environments/ruby-{version}\@yourgemset/bundler/gems

One thing I wasn't able to fix is in the GEMFILE, I have some custom git_sources, and rubymine highlights those and gives me the warning that it cannot find the gem in my bundle (you can ignore this warning; unless the gem doesn't install at all):

> gem 'somegem', custom_git:'gituser/repo'
>
> ### is highlighted and warning is "Gem x cannot be found... in SDK'

However Bundler installed it, and ruby is able to load it.

### # TLDR: Steps to have RUBYMine find extra gems, and show up in external libs

1. vim ~/.rvm/environments/ruby-{your-verion-here}\@{your-gemset}
2. add the bundler gems path to GEM_PATH entry

> export GEM_PATH='/Users/YOURUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-{version}@yourgemset/bundler/gems:{the rest}'
>
> save the file
>
> Restart RubyMine/IntelliJ, reopen your project (if not open automatically)
>
> Open the `Project Structure` dialog > `Platform SDKs` > Choose the GEMSET you're working with
>
> add `/Users/YOURUSER/.rvm/environments/ruby-{version}\@yourgemset/bundler/gems` to your classpath
>
> Hit OK, then REOPEN the `Project Structure` Dialog > `Project Settings` > `Project`
>
> *Your project will likely have no SDK* So select the one you're using again and hit OKAY
>
> RM/IJ will now reindex files
>
> You're done, any broken/missing inspection links should now be fixed. And you should be able to introspect into your gems.
>
> ## In the above instructions that when you run bundle install (from terminal or RM) it works successfully, and that you have RVM correctly setup, and gemset already created

---

I hope this helps! Let me know if I should clarify anything (happy NYE)